# React component not rendering on with latest version

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My react component was not rendering, so I suspected many things until I noticed that it only works with an older React version :

```
npm install --save react@0.14.7
```

Component was not rendering with latest React (version 16).

What should be changed to make this work with React 16 ?

webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app-client.js",
    output: {
        filename: "public/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                exclude: /(node_modules|app-server.js)/,
               loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

.babel.rc :

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["es2015"],
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

app-client.js :

```
var React = require('react');
var APP = require('./components/APP');

React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

app-server.js :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.static('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Polling server is running at 'http://localhost:3000'");
```

components/APP.js :

```
var React = require('react');

var APP = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<h1>Hello World form React</h1>);
    }
});

module.exports = APP;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use "create-react-class" (thanks to @pwolaq and @Victor), and to render with ReactDOM instead of with React :

APP.js :

```
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var io = require('socket.io-client');

//var APP = React.createClass({
var APP = createReactClass({
    render() {
        return(<h1>Hello World from React</h1>);
    }
});

module.exports = APP;
```

app-client.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var APP = require('./components/APP');

//React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`React.createClass` is deprecated for a long time. My guess is that it isn't supported since version 16.0 ([actually, I am correct](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed-deprecations))

So, since you asked what can you do to fix this, these are the options:

- stick to version < 16.0 (I wouldn't recommend that)
- use `create-react-class` package (I wouldn't recommend that either)
- migrate to `class` components (in my opinion this is the best choice)

Comment: See comment below.  Also, can you give an example for "migrate to class components" ?

Comment: first of all it's `create-react-class`, not `react-create-class`; then, you need to do `npm install` before you use it

Comment: Same with create-react-class. Not rendered

Comment: @trogne maybe this will help you: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass

Comment: It works if I use ReactDOM in app-client.js : `ReactDOM.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));`

Comment: @trogne perhaps this connects to your question `Hydrating a server-rendered container now has an explicit API. If you’re reviving server-rendered HTML, use ReactDOM.hydrate instead of ReactDOM.render. Keep using ReactDOM.render if you’re just doing client-side rendering.`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Upgrade Guide](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html), `React.creaateClass` is now available as a separate package, `react-create-class`. This is why you’re code is not working most likely.

Also, instead of `React.render`, you have to use `ReactDOM.render`

Comment: I updated APP.js,  but it's still not rendered : `var ReactCreateClass = require('react-create-class');

var APP = ReactCreateClass({
    render() {
        return(<h1>Hello World from React</h1>);
    }
});

module.exports = APP;
`

Comment: Please see my edit. (Sorry for the poor formatting. Disclaimer: I have written this on my phone. Will update the formatting as soon as I get in front of my computer)